# Using server's fingerprint in JSch library instead of setting a public key file

Tags: java, ssh, coldfusion, sftp, jsch

In my ColdFusion application I am using a Java library, JSch. SFTP server is BitVise personal edition (for testing purpose). Currently I am forcing a `StrictHostKeyChecking` and for that I create a host key repository from a file name using the below method.

```
public void setKnownHosts(String filename)
                   throws JSchException
```

Is there any way to set server's fingerprint (like `2b:16:18:83:7b:c6:5e:49:f2:f0:8e:e2:dc:64:da:1a`) instead of using a public key in JSch library?

Sample publickey reference, in case it's needed:

> localhost ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABgQCktHvR7qZv+HVOjpALTETAe9uvGsaOlqF/xGKqgOk8eEloz+3ZItjFIyHxosiQvM4NFkciAsALpWyQwCWDrF8CaAmGJv8p4nY6u2pDaMhSCcFYU/dUOSV26sc2hrALsZhu3OYG3+K1L5QGRDYQ8OVzAXf16i5sITFAS4eArmtRHHrATPyreZdA52GMl7GrHjbDToTmUsV2rPAg+ASasAS/se4QK6UGTMeWG2A9JrilcAmWl/DSfLjJclaoZz1gg8bfCqaDEf1iUWkJIOtpyt08LoQZLxXSFlcKYa/6dICFZW9E2YrAxHMOhyZpEXIf/iA79EX8aHNayVkDOh42MlX+CyB3l3thzAO0g+nAjKLoJN8KyJ9ioymQdyxnGLA8m2E+UnQ9OOznJ6ZzopnlSPQ2rygAGOW2TCHYFh+91S0=

Comment: dont understand how that thread is related to.

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own [`HostKeyRepository` interface](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/HostKeyRepository.html) in a way that the [`check` method](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/HostKeyRepository.html#check-java.lang.String-byte:A-) compares a fingerprint calculated from the `key` argument against your known fingerprint.

```
public class HostKeyFingerprintRepository implements HostKeyRepository
{
    int check(String host, byte[] key)
    {
        // Based on KeyExchange.getFingerPrint
        Class c = Class.forName(jsch.getConfig("md5"));
        HASH hash = (HASH)(c.newInstance());
        // Based on Util.getFingerPrint
        hash.init();
        hash.update(key, 0, key.length);
        byte[] foo=hash.digest();
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        int bar;
        for(int i=0; i<foo.length;i++){
          bar=foo[i]&0xff;
          sb.append(chars[(bar>>>4)&0xf]);
          sb.append(chars[(bar)&0xf]);
          if(i+1<foo.length)
            sb.append(":");
        }
        String fingerprint = sb.toString();
        if (fingerprint.equals("2b:16:18:83:7b:c6:5e:49:f2:f0:8e:e2:dc:64:da:1a"))
        {
            return OK;
        }
        else
        {
            return NOT_INCLUDED;
        }
    } 

    // dummy implementations of the other methods
}
```

Associate your implementation with the session using [`Session.setHostKeyRepository`](https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/JSch.html#setHostKeyRepository-com.jcraft.jsch.HostKeyRepository-).

Comment: so , we need to implement the interface to achieve this right?? and no other way it seems??.... Also , just to reassure myself , jsch library can be used only with sftp protocol right?? and not with ftp protocol??.... I know this question doesn't have any relevance here...but would be helpful for me to reassure myself and can find some alternative for ftp protocol.

Comment: Imo, this is the simplest approach. + Yes JSch does not support FTP.

Comment: is there any other approach using some inbuilt methods?

Comment: I already wrote that this is, imo, the simplest approach. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing wrong it seems.... Since I am not a java developer I dont want to write some codes in java instead I would prefer to play around existing methods some how..But , if no other way (not such methods ) then this is the only option. Thats the reason i was asking

Comment: I can see two other solutions, which are worse than this one, and both require implementing some (other) interface anyway.

Comment: is it possible to get a jar file with this implementation?. Currently I am using jsch-0.1.54

Comment: Do you mean implemented by someone else? This is not a correct site to hire a coder.

Comment: Yes.. I meant that....pls.Forget it , I was simply asking incase if there is any reference..May I know what does the below code do,

Class c = Class.forName(jsch.getConfig("md5"));
        HASH hash = (HASH)(c.newInstance());

Comment: It creates a class instance based on configuration option `md5`, which defaults to `com.jcraft.jsch.jce.MD5`. For your purposes your can simplify the code to `new MD5`.

Comment: Correction... create a CFC that does what Martin suggested using createDynamicProxy instead of the java code. https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html

Comment: @Ageax ... Awesome guide , does this support CF9

Comment: @MartinPrikryl.... Do we need to pass public key to the "check" method while implementing the interface?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl .. Also , it seems that the above implementation is deriving a fingerprint from a public key. But I dont want in that way , as I mentioned in the original question. I have a fingerprint(I will be getting that fingerprint from any ftp client , and dont want to deal with public generation since sftp server is not in our control) and I need to set that fingerprint using jsch library instead of a public key to connect to server with StrictHostKeyChecking as yes.

Comment: No the above implementation takes the public key as advertised by the server, calculates its fingerprint, and compares that calculated fingerprint against a hard-coded fingerprint (the one that you have). You will probably want to make the fingerprint configurable, instead of hard-coded. - You do not pass anything to the `check` method. JSch `Session` class will call the `check` method itself with the public key received from the server. That's the point of *implementing an interface*. That someone calls the interface, *not you*.

Comment: Though it stopped making a sense to me now. I've thought, that your point is, that you have the fingerprint only. But now you admit, that you do not have anything and that you [in fact want to obtain the fingerprint yourself](https://superuser.com/q/1271102/213663) (what is not the most secure approach, but ok). So why don't you retrieve a full key, if implementing the check using fingerprint is so complicated for you?

Comment: That superuser post I added because I thought there is no option without implementing the java interface. But now @Ageax said that there is a way to do this in CF itself. Keeping that idea (implementing java interface using CF) in mind, I was asking like whether we need to pass public key to the "check" method. Also , in that superuser post , I didnt say that I have nothing instead I was checking whether there is any option to get public key from any ftp client or any other tool in similar fashion how we are getting fingerprint from ftp client connection details.

Comment: Anyway , not making things complicated. Lets forget the superuser post. Will delete it later.

Comment: You didn't say that in the SU post, you said it above: *"I have a fingerprint(I will be getting that fingerprint from any ftp client ...)"*. So my concern still stays. Why don't you use a full key, if you have to retrieve it anyway. + Please do not delete the post. I've answered it already, so please do not throw my work away.

Comment: yes...and I will save that fingerprint in my config file. But I need an option in jsch to verify this fingerprint to connect to the server. Hope implementing the above interface is that option. Now , I hope we are on the same page.

Comment: No we are not. You still didn't answer, why don't you save the full key instead of the fingerprint only? Then you do not have to implement anything.

Comment: But the server administrator need to provide us with that public key right??..We have that as a second option. Our first option is handle the fingerprint (that we have in our hand) verification using jsch and accordingly to connect to the server. If this is not at all possible then we will go with first option. Hope you got me.

Comment: You seem to miss something. Maybe this: Any SFTP/SSH client, as the very first thing, receives a *full public key* from the server. GUI SFTP/SSH clients, when they do not know the key, present an user with *fingerprint* of that key. They use*fingeprint* because the actual key is too long. No human would be able to reasonable compare 2048-bit key. That's the point of the fingerprint. But *any client* always knows a *full key*. So if you are able to retrieve a fingerprint, you must be able to retrieve a full key too. Because the fingerprint is calculated from a full key on your local machine.

Comment: you mean we should get the full key (public key) from ftp client like filezila or winscp??

Comment: Also , you said that "the above implementation takes the public key as advertised by the server and do not need to pass anything to the check method. JSch Session class will call the check method itself with the public key received from the server".. Does this mean that JSch library will have the key internally and it will be available thru the '"key" argument in the check method.

Comment: Well, yes. But imo FileZilla won't show you a full public key. WinSCP does log a full key, but in somewhat different format than you need for JSch. The easiest for your is to use `ssh-keyscan` as shown in my SU answer. It will give you exactly the format you need for JSch. + Yes, `key` argument or `check` method contains a full public key.

Comment: And , I am wondering ,if JSch have the public key available then why it is not getting thru the getHostKey method?..

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: can we go the chat room pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159687/discussion-between-user3742125-and-martin-prikryl).

Comment: @user3742125 - No, it requires CF10 or higher.  For older versions, use the JavaLoader.cfc, which supports something similar. Always include your version, "coldfusion-9", etc.. in the question tags.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl... When I tried to implement the interface I am getting error saying "Util is not visible". (Util.getFingerPrint()) ... Any idea why??

Comment: OK, `Util.getFingerPrint()` is private, you so you have to copy its code. See my updated answer.

Comment: one more thing. You are saying that "Associate your implementation with the session using Session.setHostKeyRepository."... How to do this?. Need to do this in the above implementation?

Comment: No, in your code that creates and connects the `Session`.